# How to insert id's from one table to another one?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have two table one is look like that :

```
id name   roles
0  admin
1  lab 
2  user
```

second one is look like :

```
id  name 
0   xxx  
1   yyyy 
2   zzz
```

And i want to fill up table1.roles with some id(which is choosed by me) from table2.id .

For example:

```
id  name   roles
0   admin  1,2,3
1   lab    1,2
2   user   1
```

Comment: don't do that. NEVER put multiple distinct values into a single field. you'll just end up kicking yourself later.

Comment: Inline with marcB, I would suggest that you create a User_Role table (junction table) to resolve the M-to-M relationship.  In the new table you could have the Role_ID, the user_ID and the start/enddate if you wanted/needed to track history.  This way a separate record exists for each user's role; and follows normal form database design.  storing multiple values in one field fails normal form standards and makes queriing, reporting and growth more complicated.

Comment: you should create different enum for different role such as 1 means the super power, 2 means the second most super power and so on

Comment: However, if you ABSOLUTELY MUST store it in one column mySQL uses a [set dataype](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html) for this and has special commands to support it.  Just know, you'll have headaches supporting this design.

Comment: See this for a discussion of various methods : http://www.joinfu.com/2005/12/managing-many-to-many-relationships-in-mysql-part-1/comment-page-1/

Comment: See normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple and to avoid headache when it comes to updating and parsing the selected values (we really don't want to if we don't have to) I'd recommend splitting the users, the roles and the grants (the roles you wish to grant to the specific users) to three different tables. One with the purpose of storing the roles, one with the purpose of storing the users, and one with the purpose of maintaining the link between the two.

I'd start with the *roles* table:

```
id role
0  admin
1  lab 
2  user
```

Now you'll always be referring to the same roles from everywhere else in your database.

I'd then turn over to the *user* table:

```
id name   
0  John
1  Sam
2  Rocky
```

Now we've got a separate table for the users, and a separate table for the roles. No risk of mixing anything together or making duplicate entries.

To declare roles for the users, in a very easy manner, we simply turn to the *users_grants* table:

```
id user_id role_id
0  1  0
1  1  2
2  0  1
3  2  0
4  2  1
5  2  2
```

In this example the following is true:

```
Sam is an admin and an user.
John is lab.
Rocky is an admin, lab and a user.
```

Assuming you create the tables with appropriate primary keys and reference indexes. You probably want to create constraints to make sure that the same user cannot have the same role twice, it simply doesn't make any sense.

Each user can now have a set of roles, you simply delete the rows if you wish to remove their grants or add new rows for new roles for the users.

It's also possible to create a 4th table which could be defined as sets of roles, so each user is always a part of a set of roles, which can then be fixed by the admins without needing to fix the roles of the specific users, but that's a bit more advanced and not necessary unless it's a part of your requirements.

I'm pretty sure we maintain a [First Normal Form](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/first-normal-form.htm) here to ensure quality in our data.

You now should have the connection you want in a standardized manner. Feel free to ask if there's anything I can do to clarify.